# understanding a binary multiplier using gate-level diagram

Tags: binary, verilog, fpga, multiplication, synthesis

I am having problem understanding the following [code](https://gist.github.com/promach/0f46d5478735960b9efed32c0c4254f2#file-bimpy-v) (bimpy.v) that does unsigned 2-bit multiply operation.

**Edit**: Added comment from one of my friend: the following modification does the same thing with **fewer** logic !!

```
o_r <= (i_a[0] ? i_b : 2'b0) + ((i_a[1] ? i_b : 2'b0) << 1);
```

What are the purposes of the two signals (w_r and c) in bimpy.v ?

```
assign  w_r =  { ((i_a[1])?i_b:{(BW){1'b0}}), 1'b0 }
            ^ { 1'b0, ((i_a[0])?i_b:{(BW){1'b0}}) };

assign  c = { ((i_a[1])?i_b[(BW-2):0]:{(BW-1){1'b0}}) }
        & ((i_a[0])?i_b[(BW-1):1]:{(BW-1){1'b0}});
```

The code does not match the 2-bit by 2-bit binary multiplier [gate-level diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier#Example) , please correct me if wrong

[image: 2-bit by 2-bit binary multiplier]

I am also attaching a working waveform from bimpy.v for a simple 2x2 unsigned multiplier.

[image: bimpy.v waveform]

I have also generated a gate-level representation diagram for bimpy.v

[image: gate-level representation of bimpy.v]

```
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Filename:    bimpy
//
// Project: A multiply core generator
//
// Purpose: An unsigned 2-bit multiply based upon the fact that LUT's allow
//      6-bits of input, but a 2x2 bit multiply will never carry more
//  than one bit.  While this multiply is hardware independent, it is
//  really motivated by trying to optimize for a specific piece of
//  hardware (Xilinx-7 series ...) that has 4-input LUT's with carry
//  chains.
//
// Creator: Dan Gisselquist, Ph.D.
//      Gisselquist Technology, LLC
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Copyright (C) 2015,2017-2019, Gisselquist Technology, LLC
//
// This program is free software (firmware): you can redistribute it and/or
// modify it under the terms of  the GNU General Public License as published
// by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at
// your option) any later version.
//
// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
// ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTIBILITY or
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
// for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along
// with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/> for a
// copy.
//
// License: GPL, v3, as defined and found on www.gnu.org,
//      http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
//
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module  bimpy(i_clk, i_reset, i_ce, i_a, i_b, o_r);
    parameter   BW=2, LUTB=2;
    input               i_clk, i_reset, i_ce;
    input       [(LUTB-1):0]    i_a;
    input       [(BW-1):0]  i_b;
    output  reg [(BW+LUTB-1):0] o_r;

    wire    [(BW+LUTB-2):0] w_r;
    wire    [(BW+LUTB-3):1] c;

    assign  w_r =  { ((i_a[1])?i_b:{(BW){1'b0}}), 1'b0 }
                ^ { 1'b0, ((i_a[0])?i_b:{(BW){1'b0}}) };
    assign  c = { ((i_a[1])?i_b[(BW-2):0]:{(BW-1){1'b0}}) }
            & ((i_a[0])?i_b[(BW-1):1]:{(BW-1){1'b0}});

    initial o_r = 0;
    always @(posedge i_clk)
        if (i_reset)
            o_r <= 0;
        else if (i_ce)
            o_r <= w_r + { c, 2'b0 };

endmodule
```

Comment: This might be more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Andreas Is there any way to cross-post to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ without re-creating the post content ?

Comment: No idea about that, but I know that the post can be migrated to there

Comment: *"The code does not match"* .. I did not check but it may well produce the same result. To check if they are the same you could throw them at a formal verification tool or run a side-by-side simulation with all 16 possible inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**Note on MUXes**

Recall that `?` describes a multiplexer (MUX), so the statement:

`out = sel ? x : y`

is equivalent in a gate-level implementation to:

`out = (sel & x) | (~sel & y)`

(when `sel=1`, `out <= x`, when `sel=0`, `out <= y`)

If `y=0`, then the MUX reduces to an AND between `x` and `sel`: `out = (sel & x) | (~sel & 0) = sel & x`

**Deriving w_r**

Assuming `BW=2` and `LUTB=2` `w_r` is a 4-bit signal. Let's break it down:

`w_r = w_rL ^ x_rR`

`w_rL = { ((i_a[1])?i_b:{(BW){1'b0}}), 1'b0 }`

`w_rR = { 1'b0, ((i_a[0])?i_b:{(BW){1'b0}}) }`

Note how both "else" values of the MUX are zero'ed, so the MUXes are simplified to ANDs, as in the Note above:

`w_rL = { BW{i_a[1]} & i_b, 1'b0 } = { A1 & B1, A1 & B0,    0   }`

`w_rR = { 1'b0, BW{i_a[0]} & i_b } = { 0,       A0 & B1, A0 & B0}`

I replaced `i_a = {A1, A0}` and `i_b = {B1, B0}` to simplify the representation. Eventually, by XORing them bitwise:

- `w_r[0] = 0 ^ (A0 & B0) = A0 & B0`
- `w_r[1] = (A1 & B0) ^ (A0 & B1)`
- `w_r[2] = (A1 & B1) ^ 0 = A1 & B1`
- `w_r[3] = 0` (set implicitly)

**Deriving c**

Similarly, for the 1-bit `c` signal:

`c = cL & cR`

`cL = i_a[1] ? i_b[(BW-2):0]:{(BW-1){1'b0}} = {A1 & B0}`

`cR = i_a[0] ? i_b[(BW-1):1]:{(BW-1){1'b0}} = {A0 & B1)`

Eventually:

- `c = {A1 & B0 & A0 & B1}`

**Deriving o_r**

If we break down `o_r` bits:

- `o_r[0] = 0 + w_r[0] = A0 & B0`
- `o_r[1] = 0 + w_r[1] = (A1 & B0) ^ (A0 & B1)`
- `o_r[2] = c + w_r[2] = (A1 & B0 & A0 & B1) + (A1 & B1)` -- if we add them, then the sum is their XOR, and the carry is their AND, i.e: `o_r[2] = (A1 & B0 & A0 & B1) ^ (A1 & B1)`
- `o_r[3] = <carry from o_r[2] addition> = A1 & B0 & A0 & B1 & A1 & B1 = A1 & B0 & A0 & B1` (remember, ANDing with myself equals myself, i.e. `x & x = x`)

**Gate-Level diagram outputs**

Your gate-level diagram depicts the following equations:

`C0 = A0 & B0` (`=o_r[0]`)

`C1 = (A0 & B1) ^ (A1 & B0)` (`=o_r[1]`)

`C2 = (A0 & B1 & A1 & B0) ^  (A1 & B1)` (`=o_r[2]` sum)

`C3 = (A0 & B1 & A1 & B0) & (A1 & B1) = A0 & B1 & A1 & B0` (`=o_r[3]` carry)

**Why is the implementation so weird?!**

Code comments indicate that the multiplier cell is built for a specific FPGA architecture, and it looks like the original coder's intention was to fit each multiplier cell in a single LUT for that architecture. So my bet is that the original coder was trying to "guide" an old, dumb tool to build the multiplier in an FPGA-efficient way, which is usually not a gate-level-efficient way. I think that such "manual" RTL-level optimizations are useless with today's EDA tools (hopefully!).

Comment: Why "w_r[0] = 0 ^ (A0 & B0) = 0 & B0" ?
Why "o_r[0] = 0 + w_r[0] = A0 & B0" ?

Comment: you're right, it was a typo; fixed it with the correct one `w_r[0] = 0 ^ (A0 & B0) = A0 & B0`, so you get `o_r[0] = 0 + w_r[0] = A0 & B0`

Comment: " o_r[2] = c + w_r[2] = (A1 & B0 & A0 & B1) + (A1 & B1) -- if we add them, then the sum is their XOR, and the carry is their AND, i.e: o_r[2] = (A1 & B0 & A0 & B1) ^ (A1 & B1) "  <-- why sum is their XOR ? Why carry is their AND ?

Comment: I got it now regarding the XOR and AND for sum and carry

Comment: Again, there is a typo in   "C1 = (A0 & B1) ^ (A1 & A0) (=o_r[1])"

Comment: how does the manual optimization helps in fitting into Xilinx 4-input-LUTs with carry chain ? Remember that there are two XOR gate

Comment: I can't say for sure as I am no expert in Xilinx FPGA architecture; I only speculated, judging from the deliberately un-optimized RTL and the code comments. Also, typo fixed

Comment: Probably the section on "Look-Up Table (LUT) Multipliers" in http://www.andraka.com/multipli.php might help. I am still reading that article